# Heroku versus AWS - for deployment of a simple website with images

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am trying to deploy a personal website (python django based framework) which contains text and few images. Can someone tell if their are any advantages and disadvantages of deploying to heroku versus AWS.

PS: I have deployed it on AWS but the images are not loading. So I am considering Heroku but not sure if I should use Heroku or AWS would be more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS need more work but is better...

To work with images, you will need to create a bucket in Amazon S3, here is my settings to work with media and static files in Amazon S3:

```
if not DEBUG:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}

    AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
    AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'

    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'name_of_your_project.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
    STATIC_URL = 'https://{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_STATIC_LOCATION)
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    )

    CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "{}/ckeditor/ckeditor".format(STATIC_URL)

    MEDIA_URL = 'https://{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION)
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'name_of_your_project.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

Create a file called storage_backends.py in the same folder of your settings.py:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_STATIC_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False
```

You will need to install the boto3 and django-storages:

```
pip install boto3
pip install django-storages
```

Comment: thanks. I was missing the DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE.